# How do I show a partition created gParted while booting my Mac?

Tags: startup

I have a Mac Mini mid 2011, 500GB HDD with dual boot Windows 7.

I tried prepping this drive so that i can clone it to a smaller 240GB SSD using gParted from [this tutorial](http://geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-clone-hard-drive-to-smaller-drive/).

Now when I boot holding the option key, I don't see the Windows drive. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

fixed it by loading windows 7 (prepped by bootcamp) on a thumb drive then choosing th fix windows op